# which is the test statistic to use if i want to know if there is a difference between two sets of responses by different people for same question?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

i have one question - where do you buy oil from -  and two sets of responses from two different sets of people - regular buyers and rare buyers. each response set has 6 options or variable location. an image of how the data looks. [image: snapshot of question data]

how do i test if the responses vary or are different for groups?
or am i asking the wrong question?

Comment: What is your alternative hypothesis? That is, in what way do you expect there to be differences? in means? medians? variance? Without knowing your research hypothesis there is no basis for suggesting a test ... maybe add a plot of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to know if the groups are different, this is a standard test of independence for a $2 \times 6$ contingency table.  Since you have small cell counts for option 4, it is best to use Fisher's exact test in this case (which requires simulation).  Implementing this in `R` we obtain:

```
#Generate data matrix
DATA <- matrix(c(25, 19, 32, 54, 14, 20, 2, 3, 64, 4, 41, 9), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE);
colnames(DATA) <- c('Group1', 'Group2');

#Perform Fisher's exact test of independence (by simulation)
fisher.test(DATA, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 10^6);

      Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  DATA
p-value = 1e-06
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Note that the reported p-value is simulated from $10^6$ replicates, and so the true p-value is actually `p-value < 1e-06`.  In any case, we see that there is strong evidence to reject the null hypothesis of independence, and conclude that there is a difference between the two groups in the probability of selecting a particular option for where to buy oil.